# Filling value to look like similar concatenated value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i do not know how to do following issue

I have Column where can be values like 'T-00513153' but sometimes that value is concatenated with more values, like 'T-00513153, T-00513154' and what i am trying to accomplish is if value is 'T-00513153' or 'T-00513154' and in other row this value is in concatenated value like 'T-00513153, T-00513100' then for every unconcatanated value use that concatenated value, for better understanding i am posting example

[image]

Maybe with some subselect which will look if Element value is inside any value in same column (foreaching all table) and if yes, then use longest string, but i feel this approach can have performance issue, any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a question, other than "any idea"?  It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What would happen if you have two records that match your initial search Element value, but have different ending values and the same length?

Comment: Gordon: i add some more explanation.
Bernd: that could not happen because if there is concatenated value, it should contain all possible values together. The order of that values in concatenated string is allways ascending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you can accomplish what you want.  The following query finds the longest element that matches any given element:

```
select s.number, longest.element, s.val1, s.val2      
from source s cross apply
     (select top 1 s2.element
      from source s2
      where s2.element like s.element + '%'
      order by len(s2.element) desc
     ) longest;
```

You can also do this with a correlated subquery.

Note:  it is a bad idea to store lists of things in a delimited field.  You should have a separate junction table with one row per number and per element.  It would make this sort of operation much more efficient.

Comment: Can i optimize the performance somehow ? Because on small chunk of data it works, but on thousands of rows it takes forever :P

Comment: @Muflix . . . You can add a `where element not like '%,%'` so this part only runs on the single elements.  Then use `union all` to bring in the rest of the values.